# Insert div after a number of anothers divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to insert the `div-to-insert` after a specific numbers of `item` using Javascript

```
<div id="groups">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div id="div-to-insert"></div>
```

I tried this JS code but its not works :

```
$('#div-to-insert').eq(2).after('<div class="item"></div>');
```

Comment: Looks like you're using jQuery; adding that tag.

Comment: Id has to be unique, so `$('#div-to-insert').eq(2)` doesn't make any sense. There will only be 1 item of this div.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of the [`after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/) function is *what* you want to insert. Not the element you want to insert it after.

In your case I'd use the [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector directly:

```js
$("#groups > div.item:nth-child(2)").after('<div id="div-to-insert">new</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="groups">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```